# NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code:

```
def parse_pipeline(self, pipeline):
    """

    Parse the pipeline template into a fully expanded pipeline string.

    @type  pipeline: str
    @rtype: str
    """
    pipeline = " ".join(pipeline.split())
    self.debug('Creating pipeline, template is %s', pipeline)

    if pipeline == '' and not self.eaters:
        raise TypeError("Need a pipeline or a eater")

    if pipeline == '':
        # code of dubious value
        assert self.eaters
        pipeline = 'fakesink signal-handoffs=1 silent=1 name=sink'

    pipeline = self.add_default_eater_feeder(pipeline)
    pipeline = self.parse_tmpl(pipeline,
                               {'eater:': self.get_eater_template,
                                'feeder:': self.get_feeder_template})

    self.debug('pipeline is %s', pipeline)
    assert self.DELIMITER not in pipeline

    return pipeline
```

When it runs i get:

```
Setup failed: failure <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> at
flumotion/component/feedcomponent.py:443: parse_pipeline():
     'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' (flumotion/component/component.py:586)
```

I tried printing `pipeline` to check if it's None, but it's not.

What's wrong with this line?

```
pipeline = " ".join(pipeline.split())
```

Comment: `pipeline` is None during the method call

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, from where are you calling it?

Comment: What does `print repr(pipeline)` *inside* the method tell you then?

Comment: Yes, at one time pipeline is None. That causes the problem, now i just need to find out where does that None value come from.

Comment: Another option: what does `self.add_default_eater_feeder()` return? An updated pipeline? What does `self.parse_tmpl()` return? An updated pipeline? Or does either of these return `None`? Check what `pipeline` is *throughout* the method. There is no full traceback here, so methods that you called could also be complaining.

Answer (score 1):

`pipeline` *is* `None`. If you want to find out why, change the line like this and use the debugger to find out.

```
try:
    pipeline = " ".join(pipeline.split())
except:
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```